# Controlling memory variables

Tags: c#, c++, memory, assembly, masm

I don't know exactly how I'd ask this.. I'm wanting to control like the data stored in memory by locating the memory address and what not.. Kinda like cheat engine but I'm planning on doing this in MASM if it can be done easily.. If not I want to do it in C# (if thats possible also). My last resort would be c++.

Comment: So you want to find in which memory address(es) a particular pattern (number or string) is?

Comment: Going to have to be a little more specific then "and what not" ... manipulating memory of another process will be undefined behavior or hackish at best. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: What data in what memory?  Any physical memory address or memory in your process or memory in another process?

Answer (score 3):

A user process cant access other's process memory. You will need to deal with the kernel.

Comment: +1 this is how cheat engine does it

Comment: Presumably the avenue of attack will be injection into another process; Windows makes this fairly easy...

Answer (score 0):

In assembly, about all you *can* do is read and write from specific memory addresses.  For example:

```
mov eax, 0x12345678
mov 0x87654321, [eax]
```

Will write `0x87654321` into memory at address `0x12345678`.  You could do the same in C or C++ by doing:

```
unsigned int *p = (int *)0x12345678;
*p = 0x87654321;
```

I don't know about C#, but if it has pointers, you can do it!

Comment: But the VMM will prevent one process from reading or writing memory in another process.  In fact, two processes might have different pages mapped over the same address space!

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to a segmentation fault?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the OP's question - if you can read and write physical memory, you're home free.  @BlackBear - not if 0x12345678 is a valid pointer...

Comment: @Carl modern OS's (i.e. all of them) wouldn't let you do this beyond the scope of your program; only kernel modules can really access all memory

Comment: @Will, or boot loaders, or embedded devices, or any other low level application.....

Comment: @Carl Granted there are other situations in which you have full access to memory but bearing in mind he wants to create a Windows application to do this, the kernel was the only suitable example